# CSS Class Visible Only On Hover Only - Not Working

Tags: html, css

So the final result I am trying to achieve is only show  **.panel-text**  when user hovers over panel. In this case I tried the overlay CSS class, since it covers the entire div. Yet whatever I do either the text doesn't show at all no matter hovering or idle or the text is displayed always. Below is what I have tried.

```
.panel-text {
    display: none
} 

.panel-overlay:hover .panel-text {
     display: block
}
```

**The above only hides .panel-text always. Another attempt at it is below:**

```
.panel-text { opacity: 0; }

.panel-overlay:hover panel-text { opacity: 1; }
```

Now I have attempted to try  **.panel-title**  as well  **.panel-button** .

Any help is greatly appreciated, all other posts shown display what I have been using. Even if we have to display an icon when  **.panel-text**  is hidden could work out.

Somwthing link this is what should happen 

[Link](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/home)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: could you post your html code aswell?

Answer (score 0):

Do it in this way.

```
.panel-text {
     visibility: hidden;
}

.panel-overlay:hover .panel-text {
     visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, tried this method before and .panel-text was always hidden. So changing to .panel-mainimage-wrapper and using opacity did the trick. Yet I would like to use visibility since the format is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

So for some reason nothing was working when trying to use with **.panel-overlay**, so trying the image wrapper did the trick. Using visibility or display will not perform correctly still. Below CSS worked out, works exactly example provided (link) except icon, will work on that later.

*panel-text { opacity: 0; }*

panel-mainimage-wrapper:hover .panel-text {opacity: 1; }